# inline function choose criteria

Tags: c++, inline, one-definition-rule

I have the following:

```
//a.cpp
inline int f(int x) { return x; }
int g(int x) { return f(x); }

//b.cpp
#include <iostream>
inline int f(int x) { return x + 1; }
extern int g(int);
int main() {
    std::cout << g(2) << f(2) << std::endl;
}
```

The output is `22` (MSVC and GCC), that is, `a.cpp` `f` function is been inlined instead of `b.cpp` one. What's the criteria to choose the `f` function in this case?

Comment: Do you mean that you compiled and linked both a.cpp and b.cpp?

Comment: Yes. That's right!

Comment: This seems relevant: [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)

Comment: Did you turn on optimizations?  I suspect you might get a different answer for a no optimizations/debug build (with no inlining) vs an optimized/release build (with inlining).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.  All inline function definitions need to be the same in all translations units.

Since you do not do that the code is ill-formed, but it is allowed to compile and it is not required to cause any sort of warning or error.

Comment: Maybe link to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition for further details or explain ODR in more detail yourself?

Comment: _"For an inline function [...], a definition is required in every translation unit where it is odr-used."_ Says nothing about different definition. Can I say that what I presented is a unspecified behaviour?

Comment: @joãopauli no, it is UB.  See list item 1 here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

Comment: @jo - No. [It has to be the exact same definition](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#6.1).

Comment: Oh, nice! Got it!

Answer (score 2):

You break ODR (**O**ne **D**efinition **R**ule) here and have ill formed program, no diagnostic required.

Each inline definition should be identical.

Comment: Perhaps expanding on what ODR means would help complete this answer.